# Web3 Require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, web3js

Hello I'm trying to link Web3 to my html. I was using this https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js?source=post_page-----e3fbe89111c3---------------------- link.

This is my code in the html file

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
```

This is my code in app.js

```
// In Node.js
const Web3 = require('web3');

let web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8546');
console.log(web3);
```

I been trying to google answers but can't seem to find a answer for my problem.

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue and haven't figured a way out to solve this, have you ever solved this issue? None of the answers on any of the topics related to this issue helped me..

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> // In Node.js
> const Web3 = require('web3');
> ```

Look at that comment. You **aren't** in Node.js.

You're loading web3 with a script element:

> ```
> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
> ```

… so don't try to load it, in a web browser, using the method designed for use with Node.js.

(If you wanted to use that method then you would remove the script element and transpile the JS to something browser friendly using a tool like Parcel or Webpack).

Comment: What do you mean "Look at that comment. You aren't in Node.js.". I've node.js install. I'm confuse.

Comment: You have an HTML document with a script element in it. That is something that a web browser runs. It isn’t something that Node.js runs. Having Node.js installed is meaningless if it never goes anywhere near your code.

Comment: @AngeloTree: Node.js is a separate JS runtime. This code runs in the browser.

Comment: @AngeloTree You may be using the Node package manager (NPM) for installing dependencies, but you are *not* running Node.js. I hope the difference is clear.